# Validation Attribute get triggered two times

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, ninject, ninject.web.mvc, model-validation

In my MVC3 application I have the model ( not important properties deleted ):

```
public class AccountViewModel
{
    [StringLength(65)]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(65)]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is when an action is submited validation attribute called twice, and I can get 4 errors in summary, instead of 2:

```
'Property1' length must be less than 65 characters
'Property1' length must be less than 65 characters
'Property2' length must be less than 65 characters
'Property2' length must be less than 65 characters
```

I dont use Validate method in my controller's code. The problem appears also with my custom attributes, but its not happens with Required attribute. Also I have to note that ctor of the custom attributes also called twice

My action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(AccountViewModel model) {

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return View("Edit", model);
    }

    try {
        _accountService.InsertOrUpdate(model);

    }
    catch (Exception ee) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ee.Message);
        return View("Edit", model);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

On View I render my errors using:

```
@{
    var errors = ViewData.ModelState.Errors();
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-error @(errors.Count == 0 ? "hide" : "")" > 
    <h4 class="alert-heading"> You got an error!</h4> 
    <ul>
        @foreach (var error in errors) {
            <li>@error</li>
        }
    </ul>
    </div>
}
```

And I double re-check once more that ViewData.ModelState already contains errors twice.

Comment: Hmmm you have 55 in attribute declaration and 65 value in error message

Comment: can you post the action? also, confirm that you are not calling `ValidationSummary` twice in your view.

Comment: updated with action code @Steve Mallory

Comment: Yes, Im not using ValidationSummary method at all @Steve Mallory

Comment: @bogert then I don't understand where you are seeing the messages

Comment: I updated post with view markup, note that ModelState already contains double error @Steve Mallory

Comment: Have you customized the `ModelValidatorProviders`? Maybe you have registered the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` twice.

Comment: I have re-checked that, the only mention about that is "DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;" but with or without this line - no change @nemesv

Comment: Hmmm. Custom Model Binding by any chance?

Comment: Just re-checked, have no custom model binders @Steve Mallory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in integrating Ninject. If you use **Ninject.MVC** package ( I use version 3 ) it registers his own ModelValidationProvider while initializing and removes the old one:

In **Ninject.Web.Mvc.MvcModule**

```
this.Kernel.Bind<ModelValidatorProvider>().To<NinjectDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider>();
```

In **Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin**:

```
public void Start()
{
    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.OfType<DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider>().Single());
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(this.CreateDependencyResolver());
    RemoveDefaultAttributeFilterProvider();
}
```

So, rather than creating my own implementation of IDependencyResolver ( Ninject Kernel wrapper ) I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application) 
or 
you should remove Ninject.MVC package and remove its binaries from the bin folder.

Comment: The Ninject extension does not cause that problem if used correctly. Althouth w/o knowing how you set up ninject it is impossible to give you an answer.

Comment: You right, I used It incorrectly, now when it is installed correctly - everything is fine @RemoGloor

Comment: @bogert, what does "_when it is installed correctly_" mean ? could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by improper use of NInject.

To solve this issue In `NinjectWebCommon` class `CreateKernel()` method add `kernel.Rebind<ModelValidatorProvider>().To<NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider>();`

Here is the code sample.

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
                RegisterServices(kernel);
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
                kernel.Rebind<ModelValidatorProvider>().To<NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider>();
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }
```