# IValidatableObject Validate method runs twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-validation

I have a model with an Entity Framework object on it. The EF object implements `IValidatableObject` and has a Validate() method on it.

For some reason the method runs twice, so I get two identical model errors on my page.

Any idea why this happens or how to stop it?

I tried adding an `_isValidated` private member variable but it appears to be resetting to false every time it runs so it must be creating and validating two instances of the model.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CatName))
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult("Bad kitty", new string[] { "CatName", "CatName" });
    }
}
```

Edit: My model:

```
    public class KittyModel
    {
        public Cat Cat { get; set; }

        public int? SomeId { get; set; }

        public string SomeString { get; set; }
    }
```

Then `Cat` is just an EF object

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(CatMetadata))]
    public partial class Cat : IValidatableObject
    {
    public sealed class CatMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        public int? CatTypeID { get; set; }
    }

    // Some other get; only properties here

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CatName))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Bad kitty", new string[] { "CatName", "CatName" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and can you show your model? and code that use and validate model in controller?

Comment: The model validates automatically when the page is posted, before any controller actions are executed. The complete model just has an EF object on it with the above Validate method, nothing special.

Comment: @SLC Check please (if you haven't yet) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129669/validation-attribute-get-triggered-two-times and http://forums.asp.net/t/1617919.aspx?MVC+3+IValidatableObject+s+Validate+is+called+twice

Comment: The 2nd one may be correct (not entirely sure),  but I couldn't find a way to mitigate it. Any ideas?

Comment: @SLC could you show your model? Does it belong to another model with validation?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today... and I believe this is the reason that Validation Method is called 2 time, [from here](https://forums.asp.net/post/4146757.aspx):

> If your model is a complex model inside of a complex model, validation
>   might be called twice for model-level validators (which
>   IValidatableObject is considered to be). That's because it's validated
>   once as a stand-alone object, and then again as the property of its
>   containing object.